# How to Bold/format AppendLine text?

Tags: c#, email, append, console-application

Hi I would like to ask if anyone knows how to format for the `AppendLine` Method which would be then converted into a email via the `SmtpCilent` method.

The following are my codes/data which needs to be formatted:

```
var outputMsg = new StringBuilder();

outputMsg.AppendLine("The date today is : " + DateTime.Now.Date); //<==== Needs to be bolded

var body = outputMsg.ToString();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendersAddress, ReceiversAddress, subject, body);
```

Comment: Set true to `message.IsBodyHtml` and form an html. `<b>boldtext</b>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AppendLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb3sbadh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has nothing to do with formatting, as it works "on a string basis".
You need to add a string which is then rendered as bold text, e.g.:

```
var outputMsg = new StringBuilder();    
outputMsg.AppendLine("<b>The date today is : " + DateTime.Now.Date + "</b>"); 

var body = outputMsg.ToString();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendersAddress, ReceiversAddress, subject, body);
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

The [`IsBodyHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes the mail message a HTML mail, which you need for formatting.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped! Didn't know that the SmtpClient based method could be converted to html!